# Data structure, pointers

Tags: c, pointers, queue, structure

I made a queue in C using pointers, my code works but I can not understand how the pointer variable rear1 is works, because every time function called, rear1 is initialized and same for front, front store the address of start for first time then after front reinitialize but it still keep start address, how is it possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch,                                         ("pause") or input loop */
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

enqueue(struct node **start)
{
    struct node *front,*rear;
    if (*start==NULL)
    {
        *start=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        scanf("%d",&(*start)->data);
        (*start)->next=NULL;
        printf("%s","hello");
        front=(*start);
        rear=*start;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d",front->data);
        struct node *temp,*curr;
        curr=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        rear->next=curr;
        rear=curr;
        rear->next=NULL;
        scanf("%d",&rear->data);
    }
}

dequeue(struct node **front)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=(*front);
    (*front)=(*front)->next;
    printf("%d",(temp->data));
    free(temp);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct node *start=NULL;
    enqueue(&start);
    enqueue(&start);
    enqueue(&start);
    enqueue(&start);
    enqueue(&start);
    enqueue(&start);    

    dequeue(&start);
    printf("\n");
    dequeue(&start);
    printf("\n");
    dequeue(&start);
    printf("\n");
    dequeue(&start);
    printf("\n");
    dequeue(&start);
    printf("\n");
    dequeue(&start);    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To begin with, please try to reformat your code so it's readable.

Comment: Your problem would be more clear if correct punctuation and maybe more than **one** sentence are used.

Comment: Please rephrase your question, I (and probably most other readers) dont understand what the problem is.

Comment: To continue your program should not work at all. The `enqueue` function contains at least one case of *undefined behavior* as you use an uninitialized local variable. And you don't really link anything into the queue after the first call.

Comment: And pleeease format your code properly (for example the way is it done in your C textbook).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this code shouldn't work, or has undefined behaviour.

```
enqueue(struct node **start)
{
    struct node *front,*rear;
    if (*start==NULL)
    {
        *start=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        scanf("%d",&(*start)->data);
        (*start)->next=NULL;
        printf("%s","hello");
        front=(*start);
        rear=*start;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d",front->data);
        struct node *temp,*curr;
        curr=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        rear->next=curr;
        rear=curr;
        rear->next=NULL;
        scanf("%d",&rear->data);
    }
}
```

Here, when *start is defined, you assign `curr` to `rear->next`, but `rear` is undefined. You have 2 solutions:

- Using rear as a static variable (which is clearly not a good solution, especially if you want to use multiple queues)
- Using 2 struct in your main, `Start` and `End`.

I think you use `front` and `rear` as if they were static, but by default, a variable "disappear" at the end of the function where it was declared. It's a new undefined variable at each call of the function.